# USB hub not recognized on one machine

Tags: windows-xp, usb, hub

Two Windows XP SP 3 systems.

One recognizes and works with a General Electric 4-port externally powered USB hub.

The other gives a unrecognized USB device error. Tried in all ports.

What gives? Tried rebooting, etc, everything but reinstalling Windows. Is there any way to verify/reinstall the driver? It uses the Windows default driver (no 3rd party drivers required). Anything else to try?

Comment: Have you tried plugging the hub into a different USB port on the second machine? It could be dodgy port.

Comment: Cleanup. when having a problem like this, it is actually preferable to not start plugging things into port after port. But to clean up the USB devices that are no longer there. A good way to Start on this problem is unhide everything, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315539 , then unhide in the device manager, then start cleaning everything up in there that is ghosted, depending on how it looks , everything not just ghosted usb then rebooting.

Comment: Next thing i can think of, is testing the power supply for the hub to see if there is power on it. you tested the hub in another machine next would be to check your USB drivers, for "version" of the sys and dll items. or to check if motherboard drivers are installed and up to date

Comment: You have 2 machines, one works the other one does not? Before you would change the USB drivers, or try and fix them, you check the working systems drivers for usb. by opening up the device manager, and weeding through the USB items there, bringing up the properties, and seeing what the "driver" versions are. if both machines use all the same USB driver components and version. Then that is not likley the problem. See tips like this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873169 (link for Information only )